# Using XPath functions in filter mediator

Tags: xpath, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

In my inSequence of a proxy I'm filtering with a xpath query in the [filter mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB451/Filter+Mediator). But I want to use XPath functions like `exists()` or `count()`. But this does not work and always creates an exception. Here my example:

```
<filter xpath="count($body/myElement)>2">
 <drop/>
</filter>
```

And the exception I always get:

```
ERROR - FilterMediator Error evaluating XPath expression : n:exists($body/avintis:Exception)
        org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: No Such Function exists
```

How can I make these functions work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xpath functions with filter mediator as modifying your synapse segment as shown below.

```
<filter xpath="fn:exists($body/myElement)">
 <drop/>
</filter>
```

You can refer for Sample 156: Service Integration with specifying the receiving sequence available at [1] for further sample.

```
 <filter xpath="fn:number(get-property('SIMPLE_SER_AMT')) > fn:number(get-property('SECURE_SER_AMT'))">
```

[1]. http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/proxy_samples.html

Thank You,
Dharshana

Comment: This just solves the exists() function - but how do I make a count() in the xpath - this functio won't work either...

Comment: And fn:number does not work! I get the same exception as for count() or exists().

Comment: I tested sample 156 it works fine with number() function please post your synapse to see where gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how to use fn:count, you could try:

```xml
<property name="itemCount" expression="fn:count(//*[local-name()='item'])"/>
<filter xpath="fn:number(get-property('itemCount')) > fn:number(0)">
```

This works for me.

Comment: Your're absolutely correct. I found out that the xpath="" in inside the <filter> does not support many functions. Since I had may first problems, I now do the whole logic inside the property expression. So you could even do the number() inside the property.