# How to call multiple web service using conditional route mediator and proxy service in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

```
Hi I am new to wso2 .
```

I want to call two different service (different URL) using a Proxy service based on some condition

I have two different service 1) One service to add and subtract two numbers 2) Another service to multiply and divide two numbers I want to create a proxy service to call this two service based on some condition,say if 1st number greater than second number,i need to call 1st service,otherwise i need to call second service

How to implement this using a proxy service

Can anyone help me how to use Conditional route mediator to implement this

Suggest me the best way to do this,Since i am new to WSO2,please help me in brief

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With WSO2 ESB, you can do this either via [Filter Mediator](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Filter+Mediator) or [Conditional Router Mediator](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Conditional+Router+Mediator). There are many [mediators](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Mediators) and you can build your logic using desired mediators.

I would suggest you to go through [documentation](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/WSO2+Enterprise+Service+Bus+Documentation) and [samples](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Samples).

There is one sample on [Conditional Router Mediator](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Sample+157:+Conditional+Router+for+Routing+Messages+based+on+HTTP+URL,+HTTP+Headers+and+Query+Parameters), which will help you to understand on Conditional Router usage.

I think in your case, you should be able to use [Filter mediator to compare your values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000596/using-xpath-functions-in-filter-mediator) via XPath operators.

For example, see the [sample 156's filter mediator usage](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Sample+156:+Service+Integration+with+specifying+the+receiving+sequence).

If you pass your values as URL parameters, you can get those [URL parameters as properties](http://miyurudw.blogspot.com/2013/07/wso2-esb-reading-query-parametres-from.html).

Please note that these are just pointers for you to get started.

You can also try the [WSO2 Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) to [create the ESB artifacts](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS360/Creating+ESB+Artifacts).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Isuru Perera for the response.. Can you gave me sample proxy.xml for the scenario that i told,i didn't get a quick solution since i am new to wso2

Comment: Hi, I will try to give you a sample proxy.

Comment: Isuru Perera,I have modified as per your suggestion,but still i am facing another issue,can you please look on that

http://stackoverflow.com/q/22320786/2822914

Comment: Can you please help me on the below question http://stackoverflow.com/q/22397322/2822914